# C# interface and class inheritance

Tags: c#, object, inheritance, interface

I have a problem with using interface methods in my object. I'l giva a quick example without all the inplementations.

```
public class Item{}
public interface IFruit
{
      void MethodExample();
}

public class Apple : Item, IFruit
{
    public void IFruit.MethodExample(){}
}

// put this in a run method somewhere
var example_item = new Apple();

//Here comes the problem.
example_item.MethodExample();
// this will return an error saying that it cant find the method.
```

Anyway to do this?
I know for a fact that it implements the i_fruit. And has the method. Yet i cant access it?

Comment: What programming language is this? Your question is tagged with `c#` but what you have shown in your question is something rather different.

Comment: If this is C#, then I'm surprised you aren't getting an error for `method`. Also, check the capitalisation on method names.

Comment: It is c# i assure you. I just wrote method to show that it is a method without having to care about the return. Pretend it says void instead

Comment: Can you give code that reproduces the problem (and compiles). What is `Method_example`? Does it return something? What is `Var item example_item;` - just `var item`?

Comment: This is definitively not c#. Please don't use some fancy programming language to describe a problem relevant to an existing well thought-out language like c#

Comment: Now it is c#. Changed it to void instead of method since it was hard to understand.

Comment: @Mdsm you still would need to specify the return type of the implementation of `method_example` in `Class apple`.

Comment: ...and now ive made your code actually look like c# to keep the natives happy.

Comment: I thank you for the syntax correction. That wasnt the point of it. I thought people would be able to overloo generalizations for the sake of just "visualizing the problem" i was wrong. I will edit it so you guys dont get confused.

Comment: Thannks for the correction edit.

Comment: You explicitly implement the interface method so you'll need to cast to the interface or use `IFruit example_item = new Apple();` instead.

Comment: Thanks. Il look in to this

Comment: @Mdsm: Your original code contained some other problems as well, so it's not just a matter of overlooking some syntax errors. Oh well.

Comment: Yeah i dont doubt you

Comment: It was my mistake to not write all the stuff 100% correctly. I was just trying to save time hoping you guys would understand my predicament without having to run it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the syntax in your provided example does not exactly look like C#, but here is a simple example, that looks similar to yours. 
The class Item does not have an ExampleMethod, but Apple does, because it implements the interface IFruit. You can, however, use the `as` keyword to cast the object into something else temporarily, and thereby get access to the ExampleMethod. A common way to deal with this type of situation is seen in the example with `exampleFruit`. Hope this helps.

```
using System;

namespace StackOverflowInterfaces
{
    class Item { }
    interface IFruit
    {
        void ExampleMethod();
    }

    class Apple : Item, IFruit
    {
        public void ExampleMethod()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Item exampleItem = new Apple();
            // exampleItem.ExampleMethod(); -- DOES NOT WORK, because Item does not implement IFruit
            (exampleItem as IFruit).ExampleMethod();
            (exampleItem as Apple).ExampleMethod();

            IFruit exampleFruit = new Apple();
            exampleFruit.ExampleMethod();

            Apple exampleApple = new Apple();
            exampleApple.ExampleMethod();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exaclty what i needed

Answer (score 5):

First of all, please read c# naming conventions. Secondly, you have implemented `i_fruit` interface explicitly, you should cast your `example_item` into `i_fruit` or more common way is to implement `i_fruit` interface implicitly. Please read: 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mhop/2006/12/13/implicit-and-explicit-interface-implementations/

Implicit implementation example:

```
public class Apple : Item, IFruit
{
   public MethodExample(){}
}
```

On the other hand if you want to stick to explicit implementation, then you should change your code into this:

```
IFruit example_item;
example_item = new Apple();
```

Comment: Just updated your code to match the updated question I just edited.

Comment: This seems to make sense. But im not given the option to do it implicitly.

Comment: @Mdsm what do you mean you're not given the option? Given the option why who/what?

Comment: Using intellisense. It gives the option to  implement it implicitly. But the code will still be explicirly implemented.

Comment: @Mdsm then there's something you're not showing us. That only happens when there are similarly named methods in the class already

Comment: There is no other implementation anywhere. This is it

Comment: Thank you though. I might be able to solve it with the pointers you gave!